# Upload files using .Net 6 MVC model biding serialization by jQuery Ajax/JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Need to upload files using MVC model biding by AJAX jQuery/JSON.

I was uploading with a normal submit form, but now I need to change to AJAX.
How can I do this? I mean, biding using MVC and AJAX, serializing my form or something like that.

Now, my imagemPro and imagemPre, on Controller, are always 'null'.

At my View:

```
    @model Ri.Models.Produto

    <form class="settings-form" id="frmAdd" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <label for="setting-input-1" class="form-label">Título</label>
       <input asp-for="@Model.TituloProduto" type="text" class="form-control" required>
       <input asp-for="@Model.ImagemProduto" type="file" class="form-control" required>

       <label for="setting-input-1" class="form-label">Premio</label>
       <input asp-for="@Model.TituloPremio" type="text" class="form-control" required>
       <input asp-for="@Model.ImagemPremio" type="file" class="form-control" required>
                            
       <input type="button" value="Criar" class="btn app-btn-primary" id="btnAdd">
    </form>     
            
    @section scripts{
        <script src="~/admin/js/produtoAdd.js"></script>
    }
```

At my Controller:

```
[HttpPost("/api/ProdutoAdd")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProdutoAdd([Bind("TituloProduto,ImagemProduto,TituloPremio,ImagemPremio")] Produto produto, IFormFile imagemPro, IFormFile imagemPre)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, msg = "1" });
    }
   
    if (imagemPro != null)
    {
        var name = Path.Combine(_enviroment.WebRootPath + "/imgs", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(imagemPro.FileName));
        await imagemPro.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create));
        produto.ImagemProduto = imagemPro.FileName;
     }

     if (imagemPro != null)
     {
        var name = Path.Combine(_enviroment.WebRootPath + "/imgs", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(imagemPre.FileName));
        await imagemPro.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create));
        produto.ImagemPremio = imagemPre.FileName;
     }

     _context.Add(produto);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   
     return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

My script:

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var _this = $(this);
        var _form = _this.closest("form");

        var isvalid = _form.valid();

        if (isvalid) {
            Create();
        }
        else {
            //alert('false');
        }
    });

    Create = function () {
        var options = {};
        options.type = "POST";
        options.url = "/api/ProdutoAdd";
        options.dataType = "JSON";
        options.cache = true;
        options.async = true;
        contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        options.data = $('#frmAdd').serialize();

        options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        };

        options.success = function (data) {
        };

        options.error = function (res) {

        };
        $.ajax(options);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Model Binding binds the property by name attribute, your parameter name here is `imagemPro`/`imagemPre`.

2.The jQuery `serialize()` method will not include input file elements. So file user selected is not going to be included in the serialized value.

You need create a `FormData` object, append the files to that then append the form field values as well to this same FormData object. You may simply loop through all the input field and add it.

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

```
@model Produto
                                    //add `method="post"` in form tag
                                   //otherwise it will not generate token input
<form class="settings-form" id="frmAdd" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <label for="setting-input-1" class="form-label">Título</label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.TituloProduto" type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <input asp-for="@Model.ImagemProduto"  type="file" class="form-control" required>

    <label for="setting-input-1" class="form-label">Premio</label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.TituloPremio" type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <input asp-for="@Model.ImagemPremio"  type="file" class="form-control" required>
                            
    <input type="button" value="Criar" class="btn app-btn-primary" id="btnAdd">
</form>     
            
@section scripts{
      @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
      <script src="~/admin/js/produtoAdd.js"></script>
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#btnAdd").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var _this = $(this);
                var _form = _this.closest("form");   
                var isvalid = _form.valid();    
                if (isvalid) {
                    Create();
                }
                else {
                }
            });    
            Create = function () {
                var fdata = new FormData();   
                var fileInput1 = $('#ImagemProduto')[0];
                var file1 = fileInput1.files[0];
                fdata.append("imagemPro", file1); 
                
                var fileInput2 = $('#ImagemPremio')[0];
                var file2 = fileInput2.files[0];
                fdata.append("imagemPre", file2);    
                $("form input[type='text']").each(function (x, y) {
                    fdata.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
                });    
                var options = {};
                options.type = "POST";
                options.url = "/api/ProdutoAdd";
                options.dataType = "JSON";                    
                options.contentType = false;   //change here...
                options.processData= false;    //add this...
                options.data = fdata;    
                options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                };    

                options.success = function (data) {
                };    
                options.error = function (res) {    
                };
                $.ajax(options);
            };
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to create a viewModel

```
public class ProdutoViewModel
{
public Produto Produto  {get; set;} 
public IFormFile ImagemPro {get; set;}
public IFormFile ImagemPre {get; set;}
}
```

action ( remove Bind attribute too)

```
[HttpPost("/api/ProdutoAdd")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProdutoAdd(ProdutoViewModel model )
```

I recommend you to   use a submit button instead of ajax, it would be much easier for you

```
@model ProdutoViewModel

    <form class="settings-form" id="frmAdd" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       ....
           
       <input type="submit" value="Criar" class="btn app-btn-primary">
    </form>
```

Comment: I was doing with form submit.  Now I need to change to Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Your payload and your content type don't match. [jQuery.serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) encodes your form data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but you're telling the server to expect a content type of `application/json`. Easiest solution is to change the content type.

Also, you might want to use the form [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent) event of the form, rather than a 'click' event on a button. The reason for this is that browsers will submit forms in other ways besides clicking the button, (e.g. pressing "enter" key while in a text input). Submit will handle all of these methods.

Another side note: your method of creating your `options` object will work, but that syntax is a little awkward. The most common "best practice" is to declare the properties inline with the object:

```
var options = {
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/api/ProdutoAdd',
  // etc ...
  success: function (data) {
  },
  // etc ...
};
```

That keeps you from having to type `options.` before every property.